# Disjoint support of functions leads to simple integral

Tags: integration, analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+ $ and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$  with $ supp(f)\nobreakspace \cap supp(g^{3}) \approx 0 $. Is there a simple argument why then

$ \int \nobreakspace \mid f(x_1,x_2,x_3) - \prod_{i=1}^3 g(x_i)\nobreakspace \mid dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 = 2 $

$ \mid \cdot \mid $ denotes the euclidean norm.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $f$ and $g$. Are they density functions in 3 dimensions and 1 dimension?

Comment: Yes exactly, they are densities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ have disjoint supports then $\int |f-g| =\int |f| + \int|g|$ as seen by integrating over the supports $A$ and $B$ of the two functions and then over $\mathbb R^{3} \setminus (A \cup B)$. Hence the given integral is 1+1=2.